# if condition issue in the MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC app.
In controller, I have written simple code.

```
 string LastDesignation = approval.GetDesig(oPA.CreatedById);
    string CurDesignation = loggedEmployee.DType.ToString();
    if (CurDesignation != LastDesignation )
    {
        ApprovalFlow oApproval= new ApprovalFlow(loggedEmployeeId);
       foreach (var item in oApprovalFlow.ApproverEmployees)
          {
                   .
                   .
                   .
          }
    }
```

the problem is in one situation both string variable contains the same vlaues like below, 
but still satisfies the if condition and cursor goes to for loop, it supposed to exit from if condition...

```
 CurDesignation = "HOD"
 LastDesignation = "HOD"
```

completely confused, am I forgetting something while dealing with string in if loop ?

> Issue Solved...
>
> Forgot to use Trim(), there was a one space in one of the string :)

Comment: I would suggest that you put a breakpoint on the line of your `if` condition and confirm that the values really are the same.  I say that because, if your code is entering the `for` loop, the values really *aren't* the same, you've just not realised.

Comment: If your issue was solved by you don't post it in your question, instead answer your question and mark yourself as correct.

Comment: I hate it when it's something simple like that. And you're like, well I can't have those 30 minutes back.

Answer (score 0):

The strings in your if-condition are not equal. Maybe you missed something while debugging or maybe they *look* the same but are different unicode characters. But the are not equal. Try to save them somewhere, preferably to a file you can open with a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

The not equals compare both case & culture.... They might look the same (same chars & case), but the culture or some other diference might not be the same.

In c#, both != and !equals have the same behavior, so it has to be something to do with the before problem.

Comment: Issue Solved...  Forgot to use Trim(), there was a one space in one of the string :)